# Excel VBA - How to do countif more efficiently?

Tags: vba, performance, excel

I am working on an Excel VBA code for a spreadsheet. The aim of the following code is to count how many times the voucher number in this row appears in the whole column G. As the raw data has more than 60,000 rows, the following code will take more than 2 mins to finish.

```
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("AP2:AP" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(AO2=""MATCHED"",""MATCHED"",IF((COUNTIF(AQ_u,G2))>0,""MATCHED"",""NOT MATCHED""))"
```

I also tried an alternatvie way, which basically is also a CountIF function:

```
Dim cel, rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("AQ2:AQ" & lastrow)
For Each cel In Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("AQ2:AQ" & lastrow)
     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel.Offset(0, -36).Value) > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = 1
     End If
Next cel
```

Both of the codes above take a long time to finish, so I am wondering whether there is a way to make the code more efficient? Many thanks.

Comment: based on what you want to achieve try this: =SUMPRODUCT(--($G$1:$G$60000=AP1)) basically count all the values in column G that matches value in AP1. Hope it helps

Comment: @Fredlo2010 Thanks. Sorry I didn't make it clear. I need to count the value in each row which means AP1 needs to be a variable from 2 to 60,000. Can I still use your code in this way?

Comment: Turn off ScreenUpdating and Calculation; since you are only need to determine if there are zero matches vs one or more, use the `Range.Find` method instead of `CountIf`.  If that is still slow, read the ranges into a VBA array; and then implement a binary search algorithm.  Depending on your real data, you might be able to use a Pivot Table.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I think the user is trying to count.

Comment: @Fredlo2010 In the VBA code, he writes:  `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel.Offset(0, -36).Value) > 0 Then cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = 1`  That does not seem like counting to me, but rather a simple test.  And in his original code where he writes a formula to the worksheet, again he uses `COUNTIF`, but merely writes a single result if the value returned  is `>0`

Comment: @Ron yes I know but in the first few lines of the question (not code) it seems to be a count. But I could be wrong. I agree with you if the intent is just a simple found (yes/no) test then 'Find" is the way to go :)

Comment: @Fredlo2010 I agree.  But I inferred from the rest of his question that his code was working OK, just too slowly.  We'll see if/how he responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code bellow (it uses an array and a dictionary)

---

> For dictionaries late binding is slow: <strike>CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")</strike>
>
> **Early binding is fast**: VBA Editor -> Tools -> References -> Add Microsoft Scripting Runtime

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountVouchers()
    Const G     As Long = 7     'col G
    Const AQ    As Long = 43    'col AQ

    Dim ws  As Worksheet:   Dim i  As Long:     Dim d As Dictionary
    Dim arr As Variant:     Dim lr As Long:     Dim t As Double

    t = Timer:              Set d = New Dictionary

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, AQ).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Columns("AP").Clear

    arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, AQ))                'Range to Array
        For i = 2 To lr
            If Len(Trim(arr(i, AQ))) > 0 Then d(CStr(arr(i, AQ))) = 1
        Next
        For i = 2 To lr
            If d.Exists(CStr(arr(i, G))) Then arr(i, AQ - 1) = 1    'Count
        Next
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, AQ)) = arr                'Array back to Range

Debug.Print "Rows: " & Format(lr, "#,###") & ", Time: " & Format(Timer - t, ".000") & " sec"

    'Rows: 100,001, Time: 1.773 sec

End Sub
```

---

If you want to see total number of occurrences for each voucher:

```
Public Sub CountVoucherOccurrences()
    Const G     As Long = 7
    Const AQ    As Long = 43

    Dim ws  As Worksheet:   Dim i  As Long:     Dim d As Dictionary
    Dim arr As Variant:     Dim lr As Long:     Dim t As Double

    t = Timer:              Set d = New Dictionary

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, AQ).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Columns("AP").Clear

    arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, AQ))
        For i = 2 To lr
            d(arr(i, AQ)) = IIf(Not d.Exists(arr(i, AQ)), 1, d(arr(i, AQ)) + 1)
        Next
        For i = 2 To lr
           If d.Exists(arr(i, G)) Then arr(i, AQ - 1) = d(arr(i, AQ))
        Next
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, AQ)) = arr

Debug.Print "Rows: " & Format(lr, "#,###") & ", Time: " & Format(Timer - t, ".000") & " sec"

    'Rows: 100,001, Time: 1.781 sec

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! This is exactly what I need! It took me 4 secs to finish! So fast!