# VBA Loop still running slowly after optimizing

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

I am using a Duplicate search by cells selected code, as the excel documents I've been given at work for these are crashing when trying to utilize conditional formatting. I need to highlight all duplicates in a single column with approximately 200,000 cells and it currently is taking around an hour for the code to run, and the document shows "Excel unresponsive" after about 10 seconds. I am then forced to wait and hope the code is running or close the document.

After disabling screen updating, automatic calculation, and 'enable events', I noticed faster performance on smaller sections of the document, but it still runs slowly when calculating for the entire column. I have put this into various workbooks and the same slow performance occurs.

I tried to even get the status bar to appear (so I could see if the code was making progress) but had difficulty getting that to work.

```
Sub DuplicateValuesFromSelection()
On Error GoTo EH

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim myRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Selection
For Each myCell In myRange
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
    myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
    Next

CleanUp:
 On Error Resume Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
EH:
' Do error Handling
GoTo CleanUp
End Sub
```

I expect the run time of the code to be much faster than this. The current hour plus wait time seems unnecessary. Does anybody have suggestions?

Comment: Try testing the cell's `Interior.ColorIndex` before entering that `If` statement, so that if it's already 3 you can skip it.

Comment: Can't you work through a dictionary object? Going through a range of cells and using a worksheetfunction is just slow on its own I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken some inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751586/excel-vba-how-to-do-countif-more-efficiently), I pieced together a simple piece of code using a Dictionary object (early binding for speed purpose)

```
Sub Test()

t = Timer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim Dtr1 As Dictionary, Dtr2 As Dictionary
Dim Lr As Long, x As Long
Dim Arr As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1") 'Change to your needs
    Lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Arr = .Range("A1:A" & Lr).Value
    Set Dtr1 = New Dictionary
    Set Dtr2 = New Dictionary
    For x = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)
        If Not Dtr1.Exists(Arr(x, 1)) Then
            Dtr1.Add Arr(x, 1), x
        Else
            If Not Dtr2.Exists(Dtr1.Item(Arr(x, 1))) Then
                Dtr2.Add Dtr1.Item(Arr(x, 1)), 1
            End If
            Dtr2.Add x, 1
        End If
    Next x
    For Each Key In Dtr2.Keys
        .Cells(Key, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next Key
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print Timer - t

End Sub
```

I hope that would improve the runtime on your code a bit.

> ***Note:*** Because we used early binding of the Dictionary Object we need to set the right reference VBA Editor > Tools > References >
>   Microsoft Scripting Runtime

This would only highlight the duplicates.

**Edit:** Ran a timer on this procedure with a range of 200.000 rows with tons of duplicates. It processed in 2,3 seconds. :)

Comment: Need some way to get back to the first instance of a value and color it if you find any other instance of it...

Comment: Did not mean it as a criticism, and I admire your being able to walk away from your computer  ;-)

Comment: @JvdH aha - only 3:30pm here

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I have implemented the above code and it functions for me right around the 6 second run time as you mentioned. However, I am still attempting to get the first instance of the value to be highlighted (as I need all values that are duplicates to be highlighted).

Comment: One way is to add the cell reference/x value to the dictionary when adding the value for the first time: if a subsequent instance of that value is found, check the corresponding dictionary value and color that cell as well as the second instance - then set the dictionary value to Nothing/zero.

Comment: @JvdV This updated code utilizing the 2nd dictionary was the key to getting this to work! It took around 1.5 min to run, but it sure beats the hour plus it was taking before. I can now seamlessly run the filters and sort by cell color. Thank you!

Comment: @TimWilliams, I have updated my code. I ran it again and it only took 2,3 seconds. Im happy with the result. I also compared it to your awesome answer and there was no particular difference at all. Any reason why you would `UNION` your to color in batches? Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @VBACoder, both Tim Williams his answer and mine are even more optimized now taking only bare seconds :).

Comment: I'm coloring about 64k cells and without batching that up my run-time was just under a second longer.  Probably not a worthwhile optimization given it already runs relatively quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Late in the game but here's my contribution.

2.7 sec run-time on my PC.

```
Sub Replicates()

    Dim rng As Range, x As Long, arr, t, dict As Object, v
    Dim rngColor As Range, i As Long

    'set up spome dummy data
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Clear
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A200000")
    rng.Formula = "=ROUND(RAND()*500000,0)" 'adjust to increase/decrease number of replicates
    rng.Value = rng.Value

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    t = Timer

    arr = rng.Value
    For x = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(x, 1)
        If Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add v, x
        Else
            addrange rngColor, rng.Cells(x), i
            If dict(v) <> 0 Then
                addrange rngColor, rng.Cells(dict(v)), i
                dict(v) = 0
            End If
            'We're batching up the coloring by building a range and setting the color
            '  in one shot
            'Note: building large ranges is *slow* so don't let this get too large
            If i > 50 Then
                rngColor.Interior.Color = vbRed
                Set rngColor = Nothing
                i = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next x

    'color any remaining cells
    If Not rngColor Is Nothing Then rngColor.Interior.Color = vbRed

    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub

'utility sub to build up a range from single cells
Sub addrange(rngtot As Range, c As Range, ByRef i As Long)
    If rngtot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngtot = c
    Else
        Set rngtot = Application.Union(rngtot, c)
    End If
    i = i + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Now it has no use for me to update my answer :). Just kidding, will still try to adjust it according to your comments, thanks for the contribution. One thing I wonder. I read that late binding is slower than early binding. Would be interesting to test this while you are using late binding atm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how to use a `Dictionary` to count the number of duplicates. My solution will add a dictionary entry for every single cell the value appears.

For even more speed, I'm moving the entire range into a memory-based array for processing. This saves the code from having to access the Excel `Range` object each time.

```
Sub HighlightDuplicates()
    Dim valuesRange As Range
    Set valuesRange = Selection

    '--- capture the data in a memory-based array
    Dim valuesData As Variant
    valuesData = valuesRange.value

    Dim values As Dictionary
    Set values = New Dictionary

    '--- capture a list of rows for each value in the dataset
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(valuesData, 1) To UBound(valuesData, 1)
        If Not values.Exists(valuesData(i, 1)) Then
            '--- create an entry for this value and add the cell address
            '    as a reference
            values.Add valuesData(i, 1), CStr(valuesRange.Cells(i, 1).address)
        Else
            '--- append the next cell address to the list
            Dim rowList As String
            rowList = values(valuesData(i, 1))
            rowList = rowList & "," & CStr(valuesRange.Cells(i, 1).address)
            values(valuesData(i, 1)) = rowList
        End If
    Next i

    '--- now highlight the rows where the value appears on more than one row
    Dim totalDupes As Long
    Dim value As Variant
    For Each value In values.Keys
        Dim rows() As String
        rows = Split(values(value), ",")
        If UBound(rows) > 0 Then
            For i = LBound(rows) To UBound(rows)
                valuesRange.Parent.Range(rows(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                totalDupes = totalDupes + 1
            Next i
        End If
    Next value
    Debug.Print "total duplicates highlighted = " & totalDupes
End Sub
```